# In developer mode why Magento is slow?

Tags: frontend, magento-2.1.7, development, developer-mode, slowbackend

I am new to Magento and willing to make frontend theme in Magento. but it is so slow. It takes 2-3 mins to load every page. This is wasting so much time. can any one help me out. I have tried many solution like cache flush and di compile but all efforts are in vain.

I am using Magento 2.1.7 on localhost.

Comment: please check this article --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138407/magento-2-what-are-difference-between-developer-and-production-mode

Answer (score 0):

According to devdocs developer mode does following things to make development easier - 
Intended for development only, this mode:

- Symlinks to static view files are published to the pub/static
  directory
- Provides verbose logging
- Enables automatic code compilation
- Enables enhanced debugging
- Shows custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers

and because of these the development mode is really slow (mainly due to first and third ones).

Refrerence - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Comment: So we cannot make it fast. how can one developed on such slow processing...

Comment: I have noticed that it runs much faster on linux than on windows (centOS is recommended by magento), so you can try switching to linux if you are working on windows right now