# Magento2: Difference between Developer and Default mode?

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

What is the main difference between these two modes Default and Development.
And why by-default Magento2 mode is default ?

Comment: You can check out following links, they are helpful
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-modes/
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138407/magento-2-what-are-difference-between-developer-and-production-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Default mode** --> you to deploy the Magento application on a single server without changing any settings

1. Errors are logged to the file reports at a server, and never shown to a user
2. > Static view files are cached

**Developer mode** -->you are extending or customizing it.

1. > Static view files are not cached; they are written to the Magento
   >   pub/static directory every time they’re called
2. Uncaught exceptions display in the browser

**Production mode** -->it is deployed to a production server.

1. Static view files are not materialized, and URLs for them are composed on the fly.

   > Static view files are served from the cache only.
2. Errors are logged to the file system and are never displayed to the user.

**Maintenance mode** -->  take your site offline while you complete maintenance, upgrade, or configuration tasks

For more details refer Magento official document

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html