# default Vs production deployment mode in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I know the difference between `developer` and `production` deployment mode.

I looked at various posts as well as Magento [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html) though cannot figure out the main differences between `default` and `production` mode.

So, in what way `default` and `production` mode differ from each other?

Comment: Check this old post with two answers if it helps!
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138407/magento-2-what-are-difference-between-developer-and-production-mode

Comment: I have checked the answers there. Answers doesn't show clear differences b/w default and production mode there. I almost see similar behavior b/w them like **both mode hides exceptions from the user and writes them to log files.**